# Discord.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chaneld')

Tags: discord.js

This is my first question in discord.js . Here I am interested in why my code cannot read chanels that are located in `Memory/Schems/guilds.js` seems to be writing everything correctly, but nothing happens,

Error:

```js
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'chaneld')
        at module.exports (D:\bots\Bot1\commands\channeld.js:20:56)
        at Client.<anonymous> (D:\bots\Bot1\handlers\messageHandler.js:32:24)
        at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
        at MessageCreateAction.handle (D:\bots\Bot1\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:23:14)
```

guilds.js

```js
    module.exports = (guild = {id: "!", name: "!"}) => {
    return {
        id: guild.id,
        name: guild.name,
        chaneld: "id",
        members: {}, 
        prefix: "p!" 
    }; };
```

channeld.js

```js
    const {PermissionsBitField} = require('discord.js');
    
    module.exports = async(bot,message,args,argsF) =>{
        const{content,member,author,guild} = message;
        const{memGuild} = bot.Memory.guilds.get(guild.id);
    
        if(member.permissions.has(PermissionsBitField.Flags.Administrator)){
            if(args[0] == "set"){
                if(!args[1]||!guild.channels.cache.get(args[1])) return message.reply("Send Channel ID");
                memGuild.chaneld = args[1];
                return message.reply("`The channel is installed, channel: ${guild.channels.cache.get(args[1])}`");
            }
        }
    
    
        const Channel = guild.channels.cache.get(memGuild.chaneld);
        if(!Channel) return message.reply("Channel not founded");
        Channel.send({
            embeds:[{
                title: "Title ",
                color: 0xFF001A, //Red color
                description: "Description"
            }]
        });
    
        
    };
    module.exports.names = ["channeld"];
```

If you need anything else from my code, I will send you

[Image of project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4Dc5.png)